# Paypal PHP - Confirm payment cleared?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to set up a paypal checkout for an ebook, and I want it to send an email when the payment clears through paypal.

I have IPN set up, but if someone trys to use an eCheck, i'm not sure if it will tell me when it clears, or if its just saying that its pending. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

So, how can I confirm if the payment has been cleared or denied if its not an instant payment?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get an IPN notification for every step of the way.  There are many states a payment can be in.

See page #47 of this document for information on the variables:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf

Comment: excellent to know, is there any way I can test that with the paypal sandbox, eg it sending it as it validates, without me having to send individual "pings"?

Comment: @BlackWraith, I haven't programmed with IPN in ~5 years, but I remember the sandbox tools were very robust.  I suspect that there should be a way to test a variety of payment successes and failures.

Comment: Yes, 'Payment review' will let you temporarily set a payment 'under review', and release it afterwards. That should let you test this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Register as a developer there, then you can test your code using their IPN Stimulator. You can get there by clicking on "test tools", then clicking on "Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Simulator."

Make sure you change your form post action link to "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" not "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr". You can test out almost all the scenerios there. Hope this helps.